# Webview - How to trigger Java Function from Javascript Button

Tags: javascript, android, webview

So I got a problem, where there is a button that will call a webview function

The button is the one with id **play** in the **index.html** that will call the javascript **playVideo** function in **src.js**, where the **playVideo** function will notify the webview that the button has been pressed to check the condition in the **Java Function**.

How do I achieve this?

The codes are below to help getting context

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Video</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#333">
<center>
<video preload="auto" width="480" height="270" 
#Embed-video
</video>
<br>
<br>
<div>
<a class="first" href="#" id="play">Play</a>
<a class="second" href="#" id="pause">Pause</a>
</div> 
</center>
```

**Javascript code**

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var video = document.getElementById('my-video');
  var play = document.getElementById('play');
  var pause = document.getElementById('pause');

  // associate functions with the 'onclick' events
  play.onclick = playVideo;
  pause.onclick = pauseVideo;

  function playVideo(e) {
    //call java function
  }

  function pauseVideo(e) {

  }
}
```

**Java Function**

```java
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(x,y) {
                if (js.playVideo()) {
                    //do something
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use annotation for Javascript like the following example

```
    // Java File example
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "show toast from web: " + toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

```
    // Js file example
    function showAndroidToast(msg) {
        Android.showToast(msg);
    }
```

Thus, you should try like the following code.

```
    function playVideo(e) {
        //call java function
        Android.doSomething();
    }
```

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(x,y) {
                // implment your code with doSomething func here
                if (doSomething()) {
                    //do something
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    @JavascriptInterface
    public boolean doSomething() {
        // do something
        if(isPlaying) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: isPlaying means when the button pressed? If yes, how do I implement it in code? I still kinda confused

Comment: IsPlaying is kind of example for boolean you can control some implementation. You should use the annotation that is @JavascriptInterface for event what you want to use.